# Microsoft UCMA: Strings Not Being Garbage Collected

Tags: c#, wcf, sip, rtc, ucma

I am running a memory profiler on my UCMA application which works as a client that adds recorder participants to a session and I notice a lot of string instances eating up memory (even when participants are removed and after some time of inactivity I notice these strings don't get garbage collected):

```
Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration!Microsoft.Rtc.Signaling.DiagnosticsInformation..ctor( int,DiagnosticVisibility )
Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration!Microsoft.Rtc.Signaling.DiagnosticsInformation.CreateOutgoingDiagnosticsInformation( uint )
Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration!Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration.Call.SignalingSession_StateChanged( object,SignalingStateChangedEventArgs )
Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration!Microsoft.Rtc.Signaling.EventWorkitem<TEventArgs>.Process()
Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration!Microsoft.Rtc.Signaling.WorkitemQueue.ProcessItems()
Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration!Microsoft.Rtc.Signaling.SerializationQueue<T>.ResumeProcessing()
Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration!Microsoft.Rtc.Signaling.SerializationQueue<T>.ResumeProcessingCallback( object )
Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration!Microsoft.Rtc.Signaling.QueueWorkItemState.ExecuteWrappedMethod( WaitCallback,object )
mscorlib!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run( ExecutionContext,ContextCallback,object )
mscorlib!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallbackInternal( _ThreadPoolWaitCallback )
mscorlib!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback( object )
```

I see about 2000 instances like this and they're not being cleaned up. Has anyone seen this before and knows what the cause could be or if this is a UCMA issue in the framework itself?

Edit: I also see a lot of deserialization on the framework (XML deserializer object not being cleaned up?)

```
System.Xml!System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize( XmlReader,string,XmlDeserializationEvents )
System.Xml!System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize( XmlReader,string )
Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration!Microsoft.Rtc.Signaling.XmlHelper.DeserializeObjectFragment( byte[],XmlSerializer )
Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration!Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration.Conferencing.ConferenceJoinCommandResponse.TryProcessResponseCore( SipMessageData,ref RealTimeException )
Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration!Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration.Conferencing.EstablishFocusSessionsAsyncResult.ParticipateCallback( IAsyncResult )
Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration!Microsoft.Rtc.Signaling.CompletionCallbackWorkItem.Microsoft.Rtc.Signaling.IWorkitem.Process()
Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration!Microsoft.Rtc.Signaling.WorkitemQueue.ProcessItems()
Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration!Microsoft.Rtc.Signaling.SerializationQueue<T>.ResumeProcessing()
Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration!Microsoft.Rtc.Signaling.SerializationQueue<T>.ResumeProcessingCallback( object )
Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration!Microsoft.Rtc.Signaling.QueueWorkItemState.ExecuteWrappedMethod( WaitCallback,object )
mscorlib!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run( ExecutionContext,ContextCallback,object )
mscorlib!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallbackInternal( _ThreadPoolWaitCallback )
mscorlib!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback( object )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Garbage collection is not triggered by `some time of inactivity`.  There is nothing wrong with seeing a lot of instances of string or any other class in memory. And interned strings (compile time constants) are never collected.

You don't have a memory leak until you get an Out-Of-Memory exception.

Comment: But what if you see memory go up and...well, not come down for that process? ...and when you profile that process...you see 3000 new instances from a snapshot you took and compared to a snapshot of when it was first run, and...after a Gen #2 Garbage Collect invocation a day later from when there was no more activity, you see only 50 instances of type String have been cleant and the rest are just sitting in memory and taking up hundreds of MB of RAM, easily viewed in Task Manager? Is that NOT a memory leak?

Comment: No. Real memory leaks are not even possible with a GC. You can mismanage your references but that's a matter of program logic. As long as you don't see an OOM, what's the problem? Memory is cheap and virtual.